# Create power bi relational table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table that is loaded automatically

[image: table1]

I need to somehow create a table that relates the part number and components at all levels, returning the result as below.

[image: result]

I want to be able to query a given part number and see all possible components and subcomponents

I tried using some dax formulas and the editor itself, but I can't reach my goal

Comment: Have a look at [Parent and Child functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax)

Comment: Did answer below work for you?

Comment: Thanks, this works with the example data!

with my original data it gave the error:
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Number and Text.
Details:
     Operator=&
     Left=1324567
     Right=:


but it helped me a lot, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Buffer(Table.Group(Source, {"Parent"}, {{"ImmediateChildren", each let a=_[Parent]{0} in List.Transform(_[Child], each a&":"&_), type table}})),
ParentList=List.Buffer(#"Grouped Rows"[Parent]),

Process =  (n as list) as list =>
    let children = List.Combine(List.Transform(List.Transform(n, each List.PositionOf(ParentList,Text.AfterDelimiter(_,":"))), each try #"Grouped Rows"{_}[ImmediateChildren] otherwise {})) 
    in  if List.Count(children)>0 then children & @Process (children) else children,

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Children", each [ImmediateChildren] & Process([ImmediateChildren])),
#"Expanded Children" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Children"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Expanded Children", "Children", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"LowerParent", "Child"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"LowerParent", "Child"},Source, {"Parent", "Child"}, "Merge", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Merge" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Merge", {"Qty"}, {"Qty"}),
#"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Merge", {"Parent", "Child"}, {{"Qty", each List.Sum([Qty]), type number}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows1",{{"Parent", Order.Ascending}, {"Child", Order.Ascending}})
in  #"Sorted Rows"
```

Input:

| Parent | Child | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 1 |
| A2 | B1 | 2 |
| A2 | B3 | 3 |
| A3 | B3 | 4 |
| B1 | C1 | 5 |
| B1 | C2 | 6 |
| B2 | C1 | 7 |
| B2 | C3 | 8 |
| B3 | C3 | 9 |
| C1 | D1 | 10 |
| C2 | D1 | 11 |
| C2 | D2 | 12 |
| C2 | D3 | 13 |
| C3 | D3 | 14 |

PartialOutput:

[image]

I await Ron's List.Generate version